# How to create custom date picker field type in WFFM

Tags: wffm

I created **customdatepicker.cshtml** file in `\Form\EditorTemplatesfor` path and selected in form designer window. When I browse the page which has this WFFM and and click on `customdatepicker` field it's not opening any date control.

Can you any one suggest me that how can I implement a custom date picker field type?

Comment: First, WFFM provides OOTB date field, what do you want to achieve? second, did you follow this article to create your field? - https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/82/web-forms-for-marketers/en/create-a-custom-field-type.html

Comment: My requirement like, want to disable the previous dates (with current date) and will implement some custom JS stuff. And beside date field want to show time as well.

Comment: Sounds like you just need to use a custom validator. See this question: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/5929/how-to-prevent-a-user-from-entering-an-invalid-date-within-wffm - it solves the same problem you are trying to solve